# IE 11 and possibly others have missing features?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I've been working on this website for a very long time now and only now I've noticed a few things that are missing when you use Internet Explorer.

Have a look with me: http://reclameabcshop.nl/

If you visit that website on Internet explorer 11, you'll instantly notice that the cartoon character is blocking 1/3 of the logo. There's also some content missing from the css file, for example the arrows in the navigation, the search icon in the search bar and the right arrow to sign up for our newsletter.

I have no idea how to solve this.
Added the following to the header:

Tried out: /* IE 11 only */
Tried to put the \9; behind a css code

I hope that this makes sense, if not then please, ask away.

Comment: For `.funnyguy` to be near the center, use `display: block` on the wrapping `<a>` tag...

Comment: I've tried to edit this with the inspect element tool in internet explorer but it doesn't seem to change it. I've tried to use display:block; on .funnyguy, body >.wrapper and the logo itself.

Comment: You have errors in your HTML; If you correct those, does that help things? (Different browsers respond differently to errors.) If not, can you make a jsfiddle or a snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: You still missed the `<a>` link itself, I conclude from reading the comment. That works for me.

Comment: @Shikkediel I tried to do .wrapper a { display:block; } which worked, but it completely broke the top bar and removed the horizontal alignment that the list has, am I still missing something?

Comment: You could try to target it a bit more specifically, `.header > a` for example. With such a global selector you were using, many more `<a>` tags would be affected. Mooie stad achter de duinen trouwens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Shikkediel got it!

> You could try to target it a bit more specifically, .header > a for example. With such a global selector you were using, many more  tags would be affected.

That did the trick for me! 
A simple .header > a { display: block; } did the trick.

Case solved, thanks for everyone who put their time into helping out.